# Script that will reboot PC on specific GPU temp

Tags: scripts, reboot, automation, temperature

Recently I've started mining litecoins. My miner consists of 3 Radeon R9 290x GPUs. From time to time one of them (not a specific one, it happens randomly) stops mining. Usually restarting cgminer (mining program) doesn't help, the only thing that helps is reboot. Next week I'm leaving for 8 days and I have nobody to do that for me so I thought of a script that would do that automatically.

The script would have to periodically verify if all GPUs are working and if not - reboot.
I think temperature reading is the easiest thing to determine if all cards are working. I know how to read temperature, reboot, add stuff to cron. What I don't is how to put it all together.

Get temperature command:

```
 aticonfig --odgt --adapter=all | grep Sensor:
```

Output looks like this:

```
 Sensor: Temperature - 77.00 C
 Sensor: Temperature - 77.00 C
 Sensor: Temperature - 77.00 C
```

I would like the script to read the numerical value and reboot if it drops below XX.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: I've just noticed that on my PC aticonfig --odgt --adapter=all shows really only temp of GPU0. Three times. When I do aticonfig --adapter=1 --odgt it also shows the temp of GPU0. Even when I do aticonfig --adapter=7 --odgt it keeps returning the temp of GPU0 despite the fact that GPU7 does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save this a script and make it executable (`chmod +x scriptname.sh`) and run it with bash using `sudo` as `reboot` requires root.

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
    temp=$(aticonfig --odgt --adapter=all | grep Sensor: | sed 's/[a-zA-Z:-]//g'|  tr -d ' ')

    action=$(echo $temp|awk '{ print ($1 < 76) ? "reboot" : "" }')

    $action
    sleep 1
done
```

I have not tested it with the ATI command as I don't have access to the command, but it works replacing `aticonfig --odgt --adapter=all | grep Sensor:` with `echo 'Sensor: Temperature - 77.00 C'`. This was how I tested it.

The 76 is the restart temp. You can edit that.

Comment: When I change "reboot" to "echo blabla" it just keeps echoing blabla despite having changed the temp to 50 and the real temp being 78. Suggestions?

Comment: I know. I replaced > with < and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I have corrected the > to < now. I didn't read carefully, I assumed you had an overheating problem!!

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
while true; do
  aticonfig --odgt --adapter=all | 
   awk -vt="$1" '(/Sensor:/ && $(NF-1) < t ){exit(1)}' || reboot 
   sleep 10 
done
```

Save the script above as `gpu_temp.sh`, make it executable and run it with the temperature limit you want as an argument:

```
/path/to/gpu_temp.sh 77
```

I don't have an ati card so I can't test this but that should cause your machine to reboot if a GPU core falls below 77 °C.

---

#### Explanation

- The `while true` starts an endless loop, the script will run until killed.
- The `awk` line checks if the next to last field (`($NF-1)`) of lines containing `Sensor:` is less than whatever you chose and, if so, exits with exit status `1`.
- The command to the right of `||` will be  executed if the command on the left failed, if it exited with non-zero status. So, if one if the cores is below a certain temperature, the `awk` script will fail and the system will be rebooted.
- `sleep 10` just pauses the script for 10 seconds so you don't flood your system with requests.